# Multiple products but single sign on

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, aspnetboilerplate

I am developing several products using Aspnetboilerplate, all of them are multi-tenant enabled. I dont want users to have separate logins for each product. Can I use one of the products as a hub for all logins, roles, and permissions?

Comment: For login, you can [configure Identity Server](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Identity-Server). Roles and permissions are application-specific (per-product) and should be handled in each product.

Comment: as @aaron says, use Identity Server for sharing the same credentials.